# Query how many items to show in shortcode

Tags: posts, shortcode, query

I am building a shortcode that will display my custom post type (portfolios). I want to add another option to add how many items to show.
This is what I have for now, but it shows all items, and I need to add a 'items' shortcode_att but not sure how to call it in the query later. Thank you!!

```
add_shortcode( 'type_portfolio', function( $atts, $content = null ){
$atts = shortcode_atts(
array(
'column' => '3',
'category' => '0'
), $atts);

extract($atts);

$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type'      =>  'fen_portfolio'
);

if(  $category > '0' ){
$args['tax_query'] = array(
  array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'taxonomy' => 'cat_portfolio',
    'field' => 'term_id',
    'terms' => $category
    )
  );
 }

$portfolios = get_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_shortcode( 'type_portfolio', function( $atts, $content = null ){
$atts = shortcode_atts(
array(
'column' => '3',
'category' => '0',
'ppp' => -1
), $atts);

extract($atts);

$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
'post_type'      =>  'fen_portfolio'
);

if(  $category > '0' ){
$args['tax_query'] = array(
  array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'taxonomy' => 'cat_portfolio',
    'field' => 'term_id',
    'terms' => $category
    )
  );
 }

$portfolios = get_posts( $args );
```